# How do I change "USER" namespace at nodejs Cache Intersystems

Tags: node.js, intersystems-cache

I am try to run example from cache.node module:

```
var globals = require('cache');
var data = new globals.Cache();
data.open(
    { path:"/usr/cache/mgr/",
      username: '_SYSTEM',
      password: 'SYS',
      namespace: "IKSTEST"
    },
    function(error, result){
        console.log("error ",error);
        console.log("result ",result);
}
  );
console.log(dirList);
var dirList = data.global_directory({}).toString()
data.close();
```

but returned data from "USER" namespace:

```
# nodejs cache.js 
Testtest,Testtest2,Testtest3,Testtest4,Testtest5,Testtest6,zewd
error  0
result  { ok: 1, global: '/usr/cache/mgr/', result: '1' }
```

Does anyone know how I can change CACHE namespace from nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug where Caché node.js driver ignores namespace in `open` is fixed in Caché 2014.1 and later.

Comment: after update to cache2014.2 `open` worked fine, thank you

Comment: @antonov-iv. Notice, there is no such release as 2014.2. It was fieldtest, that was later renamed to 2015.1. Please use released versions!